# Issues starting Spring Cloud CLI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm learning about microservices and I need spring cloud cli for this test project.

I have installed spring boot cli (extracted and added to path) version Spring CLI v2.0.3.RELEASE.

I have installed the spring cloud cli plugin (spring-cloud-cli:1.3.1.RELEASE), and verify it with checking its version.

I would like to execute [spring cloud eureka configserver zipkin]
but I'm getting:

> File ........\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\launcher\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer\1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar must exist

Comment: Why are you using an old version of the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with 1.4.0.RELEASE (2.0.0.RELEASE isn't out yet, but should be soon). You probably have a bad jar file in your local maven cache (e.g. the one that it complains about).

Comment: I have tried to remove the whole cloud directory from the local m2 cache, and retry the setup with spring boot cli version 1.5.9 and spring cloud cli 1.3.3 but now im getting " IllegalArgumentException: File must exist "